# Could not convert from brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, initialization

I am trying to compile the code below but I keep running into the error
`could not convert '{{1, 2}, {5, 6}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Class1'`. I am compiling the code in `-std=c++11`. Is my initialization wrong?

```
class Class1
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> > a;
    Class1(vector<vector<int> > p)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                a[i][j] = p[i][j];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class1 ClassValue =   {{ 1, 2, },{ 5, 6 } };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Add another set of braces](https://godbolt.org/g/9ezz9v). You are roughly calling `Class1({1, 2}, {5, 6})`, which is 2 parameters to a function that only takes 1.

Comment: And your constructor is useless, it's by default.... In fact, your constructor is wrong, `a` is not resized.

Comment: OT: note that those loops are unnecessary to copy the vector. All you'd have to do is write `a = p`. It could also be done in the member initializer list (`Class1(...) : a{p} {}`). You are also copying twice instead of just once, so you should probably write `Class1(...) : a{std::move(p} {}`

Comment: The loop is bad to begin with, even if it worked.  You shouldn't use magic numbers like `2`, or even variables to determine the number of entries.  The `vector` has a `size()` member function -- use it to determine the number of entries, not magic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your line to:

```
Class1 ClassValue ({{ 1, 2 },{ 5, 6 } });
```

Second thing is your constructor is invalid, as you write to non-existing memory. Instead, use:

```
Class1(vector<vector<int> > p):a(p){}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT: This one will be better (faster), as you don't copy second time.

```
Class1(vector<vector<int> > p):a(move(p)){}
```

Comment: `a{std::move(p)}`, as you are copying twice, otherwise.