# C++ segmentation Fault while doing Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to execute this code which overloads a * operator to multiply 2 matrices Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 and store it in Matrix 3. I can print the matrix fine using PrintVector() function although as soon as the code reaches the overloaded function(it prints the "Reached here" statement successfully) I get a segmentation fault. Been trying to figure this for a while, I can't see what's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Class1
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;

    Class1(vector<vector<int> > p):matrix(move(p)){}

    //This function is used to perform the multiplication operation between two square matrices
    Class1 operator*(const Class1 &mat1)
     {
        int count = 0;
        vector<vector<int> >  tmp;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {

              tmp[i][j]=0;
              for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
              {
                  cout<<count++<<endl;
                 tmp[i][j]=tmp[i][j]+(matrix[i][k]*mat1.matrix[k][j]);
                 cout<<tmp[i][j]<<" ";
              }
           }
        }
        return tmp;
     }

    void PrintVector()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Class1 Matrix1 =   {{{ 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                       { 5, 6, 6, 8 },
                       { 9, 8, 7, 6 },
                       { 3, 2, 1, 1 } }};

    Class1 Matrix2 =   Matrix1;

    cout<<"Reached here"<<endl;
    Class1 Matrix3 = Matrix1 * Matrix2;

    Matrix3.PrintVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tmp` is an empty vector. `tmp[i]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing index out of bounds, for any value of `i`.

Comment: Segmentation fault simply means your program accessed memory outside what it had allocated/is allowed to use. *Often* this is due to dereferencing a null pointer, but it doesn't have to be. Check your memory accesses and make sure they are all within allowable bounds.

Comment: Thanks @Igor Tandetnik resizing tmp worked

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so all I needed to do was resize tmp. Thanks @Igor Tandetnik

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



class Class1
{
public:
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;

    Class1(vector<vector<int> > p):matrix(move(p)){}

    //This function is used to perform the multiplication operation between two square matrices
    Class1 operator*(const Class1 &mat1)
     {
        int count = 0;
        vector<vector<int> >  tmp;

        tmp.resize(4);
        for(int t=0;t<4;t++)
            tmp[t].resize(4);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {

              tmp[i][j]=0;
              for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
              {
                  cout<<count++<<endl;
                 tmp[i][j]=tmp[i][j]+(matrix[i][k]*mat1.matrix[k][j]);
                 cout<<tmp[i][j]<<" ";
              }
           }
        }
        return tmp;
     }

    void PrintVector()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Class1 Matrix1 =   {{{ 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                       { 5, 6, 6, 8 },
                       { 9, 8, 7, 6 },
                       { 3, 2, 1, 1 } }};

    Class1 Matrix2 =   Matrix1;

    cout<<"Reached here"<<endl;
    Class1 Matrix3 = Matrix1 * Matrix2;

    Matrix3.PrintVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, I do not think you have done some research on the topic. For instance, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142815/generic-matrix-type-in-c), you can see that you need to initialize first, and then do operations on `vector`s. This was also the _very same_ comment you [have received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090575/could-not-convert-from-brace-enclosed-initializer-list#comment85186703_49090575) under _another_ question of yours.

Comment: @Arda Aytekin I apologize, but to understand vector better I watched this youtube tutorial and at 6:58 minutes in the video he mentions the value is automatically initialized to zero, I got this value initializing he mentions confused with memory space initializing and assumed its not necessary, I'll take care of this in the future. Thanks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGyutdso6_c

Comment: The example in the video considers `vector<int> v(3)`, which is the second constructor in the [constructor list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector`. However, in your example, you have `vector<vector<int>> tmp`, which is the first version in the aforementioned list. And it is very clear in the explanation in the webpage that you are constructing an empty container with the default constructor. This is gonna be valid throughout your custom matrix implementation.